# Change class of the menu on scroll in angular + bootstrap

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular and I am simply trying to switch between two bootstrap defined menu classes on scroll. What I am trying to achieve is that the menu stays fixed to the top with changed background (as provided in bootstrap css) when scroll is not on top of the page. I have tried using ng-class, but nothing is happening. The google chrome inspector doesn't report any errors. Here is what I have so far:

html:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app = "cvApp">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>CV creation</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Theme CSS -->
    <link href="assets/bootstrap/css/clean-blog.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter:400,700">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
<body style="background-color:#FF0000;">
<div>
<nav class = "navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top"
ng-class="{'navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top is-fixed is-visible':boolChangeClass}">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->


        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" >
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a href="post.html">Save</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="contact.html">Export</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
</div>
<div>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></div>

<script src="js/angular.min.js?q=123"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route.min.js?q=123"></script>
<script src="app/cvapp.js?q=123"></script>
<script src="app/Controllers/MenuController.js?q=123"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

module "cvApp" with directive:

```
var cvApp = angular.module('cvApp', []);

cvApp.directive("scroll", function ($window) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
             if (this.pageYOffset >= 0) {
                 scope.boolChangeClass = true;
             } else {
                 scope.boolChangeClass = false;
             }
            scope.$apply();
        });
    };
});
```

I would like some insight on what I am doing wrong and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the code that you have provided, i can not see you using the directive in the markup anywhere.

change your markup to :

```
<nav scroll class = "navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top"
ng-class="{'navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top is-fixed is-visible':boolChangeClass}"> ...
```

and it would work.

Here is a basic fiddle for example (doesn't include bootstrap, but you can see that the class is being applied on scroll, the background of nav changes from red to green):

http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/13347/

Comment: Thank you very much, I knew I was overlooking something simple.